# So, stress (specifically PTSD) can be caused while you're young or older. But is it less likely to go away as you get older?

Tags: ptsd

I know PTSD can occur with many people. But does age influence whether or not you can get over it? For example, someone who was a vet in Vietnam compared to someone who went through a robbery as a kid. Which one would be more likely to recover from their PTSD?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. To make a valid comparison similar causes would need to be used. The causes of combat related PTSD can be very different to PTSD caused by other triggers. There are so many different factors that can be at play - role, duty orders etc. that if there was any scientific data comparing recovery times etc. they would be invalid. If you was to compare a robbery victim/witness who was young compared to a robbery victim/witness who was older by a decade or 2 may be a good comparison but there would need to be strict controls on the comparisons between the victims/witnesses..

Comment: ...The idea of the question is a good idea, however, I am sorry but I would be very surprised if any answer could get given which isn't purely opinion-based which would be off-topic here.

Comment: Your question has three components, I think. Separating them might get better answers.

(1) Are some types of trauma more likely to lead to PTSD than others?
(2) Is the same type of trauma more likely to lead to PTSD at one age than another?
(3) What factors drive who recovers from PTSD and who continues to have symptoms?